# Why is Google Sheets counting this cell as both blank and not blank?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Google Sheets appears to be counting my blank cell as both blank and non-blank.

The cell in question, A1, is filled with this formula: `=IF(1=0,"Some output","")`. The output, of course, is an empty string, since 1 does not equal 0.

Using `countif`, I'm running into the problem that it is counting that cell when I use both the comparison `"<>"` and `""`. So a cell with `=COUNTIF(A1, "<>")` returns 1, and a cell with `=COUNTIF(A1, "")` also returns 1.

In Excel or LibreOffice Calc, the values of the two `countif` functions line up with my expectations, depending on if the cell A1 has a resulting value or not. But Google Sheets can't make up its mind on if the cell is blank or not and ends up counting it both times. (It doesn't count it for both if there is a value returned, nor does it count it both times if A1 is truly empty with no formula.)

Is there something wrong with my formulas? Or is this a bug in Google Sheets? I'd like to be able to correctly count or ignore blank cells in another formula.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these instead:

`=COUNTIF(A1,"<>"&CHAR(0))`

or

`=COUNTIF(A1,"<>"&NULL)`

Either will return the expected result of 0 if the formula `=IF(1=0,"Some output","")` resides in A1.

Comment: adding a little more context would help others understand what they should see if they pick one of these options.

Comment: mhoran_psprep, the OP asked why two different COUNTIF formulas were saying that his A1 formula =IF(1=0,"Some output","") was returning a result that was both blank and not blank, instead of blank. Specifically, he wanted =COUNTIF(A1, "<>") to return 0, but it was returning 1. Using either of my suggested formulas will return 0 as he hoped, by separately appending the ASCII null character code - CHAR(0) - or the NULL keyword.

Comment: And if you add that explanation the answer becomes better.

Answer (score 1):

Actually yes, your formula syntax is wrong. Google Sheets is more sensitive so your formula in **A1** cell should be:

```
=IF(1=0, "some output", )
```

This way the **`FALSE`** part of **`IF`** function prints "the true nothing", while having a pair of double quotes is considered as "printing something with no length".

[image: 0]